# How can I change Bootstrap3 tabs using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I want to change those tabs on response HTTP response request.

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you.**

Comment: with `ui.bootstrap` you can use [`uib-tab`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs) by changing `active` attribute value

Comment: Have a look at: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/